# Send object file data from javascript to php, and store the file in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm in trouble sending an object file from an input type file, i try to convert the object file to base64 to store it in the db with FileReader but it doesn't work, help please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit()
{
    var data = document.getElementById("actualizar");
    var file = data.files[0]; //object file that i want to send
    var size = file.size;
    var name = file.name;
    var type = file.type;
    var value = file.value; //fakepath
    $.post("updfile.php", {name : name, size : size, type : type}, function(data){   

    });
};
```